# How to display text for an item in a list view Android Studio

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring this out. What I want to do is display a different description depending on which item I click from a list view. Let's say I choose the third recipe on the list. It should switch to another activity and show the description for that recipe only and not any other recipe. I have the descriptions in the strings folder.

In my code, it has a listener and an intent to open the other activity. When I run the app, once I click on the item on the list, it closes. Before, I did not use a listener, but a method and have an onClick for the textview and image view in the xml. That would switch the activity, but would not show any description.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {                                           
private RecipesDataSource ds;                                                               
private ListView recipesListView;                                                           

@Override                                                                                   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                                                 
    ds = new RecipesDataSource();                                                           
    recipesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);                               
    recipesListView.setAdapter(new RecipesDataSourceAdapter(this,ds));                      
    recipesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {          
        @Override                                                                           
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecipesInfoActivity.class);            
            i.putExtra("recipe_desc", position);                                            
            startActivity(i);                                                               
        }                                                                                   
    });                                                                                     
}                                                                                           

}
```

Here is the second activity where I want the description to appear. It has a text view for holding the text.

```
public class RecipesInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView recipeInfo;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipes_info);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    recipeInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recipeInfoTextView);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String pos = i.getStringExtra("recipe_desc");
    recipeInfo.setText(writeDesc(pos));
}

public int writeDesc(String pos)
{
    int position = Integer.parseInt(pos);
    int desc = 0;
    if(position==0)
    {
        desc = R.string.description1;
    }
    else if(position==1)
    {
        desc = R.string.description2;
    }
    else if(position==2)
    {
        desc = R.string.description3;
    }
    else if(position==3)
    {
        desc = R.string.description4;
    }
    else if(position==4)
    {
        desc = R.string.description5;
    }
    else if(position==5)
    {
        desc = R.string.description6;
    }
    else if(position==6)
    {
        desc = R.string.description7;
    }
    return desc;
}

}
```

The method `writeDesc()` returns the description depending on the position that `putExtra()` passes from the `MainActivity`. The variables are ints because I'm using an `ArrayList` with Integers.

Please don't give me complicated code since I'm new to Android Studio. If you have a solution to offer, please make as simple as possible.

Summary of what I need help with:

-Writes a description on a second activity depending on which item is clicked from a listview. Ex: If I click on a recipe for chicken, it will show the recipe for chicken(I have these descriptions as strings, so you don't need to worry about that.)

-Should I use the listener or a separate method that is called when the item is clicked from the listview(uses `android:onClick="whatevermethodnamehere"` in xml instead of how it is now in the main activity with a listener). Listener, for some reason, does not switch to the next activity and crashes, but the `onClick` does not crash and switches, but no description is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already figured out the difficult part i.e. using `ItemClickListener`, I believe you just need some direction, so here it is.

Based upon position, put different text in your `intent.putExtra`

e.g. instead of `i.putExtra("recipe_desc", position);` 
use this  `i.putExtra("key","recipe_desc");`

Now it is upto you how you wish to do it. I have 2 flavors as quick suggestions
Flavor1: Make a mapper class that maps `recipe_desc` with proper descriptions. e.g. if you receive "chicken" in your `recipe_desc`, then this mapper class contain chicken receipe mapped to it. In `activitB`, simply use `switch-case` for get the correct value

Flavor2: instead of using mapper class in activityB, directly put the description into your `intent.extra` based upon position. Now just display whatever you get from intent. So in flavor2 your `switch-case` moves to `activityA`

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the writeDesc method return a STRING of the description instead of an integer. Looks to me like you are just returning int values...

Comment: I'm returning int because there is a red line under the code if I change it to String. I think it is because the array list I'm using that contains the descriptions is int. It works for the name of the food, but for some reason it doesn't work for the description.

Comment: You got an error because R.string.description will return an interview. What you need to do is change the return type to string and replace R.string.description with getResources().getString(R.string.description) and that will return the string value that you want. Also, change the type of desc to String